# Make Graphic window in java for Python/Pygame programmer

Tags: java, python, pygame

I learned Python as my first language, and have made several games with Pygame, but recently I am learning Java, largely for the fact that it is faster then python.  I'm learning it with this "http://fpl.cs.depaul.edu/jriely/java4python/index.html" but it never teaches making a graphics window.

So how am I to make graphics?  After all a text-based game solely in the console is rather limited!

Comment: No language is faster than another language. It is only implementations of the languages that can be compared in terms of execution time under a specific benchmark that tests a singular task.

Comment: If you are only switching because python is too slow you should give [PyPy](http://pypy.org/) a try. If it's still too slow you can try [Cython](http://cython.org/) which basically gives you "C speed". If you have numerical (vectorizable) computations you can try [Numpy](http://www.numpy.org/). Python is rarely used for games not because of speed, but other problems, namely packaging and missing support/libraries.

Comment: I'm learning java for more reasons then speed, it was just one of the reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is quite ambiguous, however

Java has a Graphics library which you can use to draw a variety of things.
Take a look at the oracle documentation for Graphics [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)

You could also take a look at a beginners tutorial in how to use the Graphics library [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/basic2d/) since you say you are still learning Java.

On the other hand, if you're looking to create a user interface, you should take a look at the swing framework within java which allows you to create components and add them to the window frame (Jframe) and set its layout to manipulate where they appear.

To get started, you could create a class that extends JFrame and then add components there.

```
public class MyWindow extends JFrame {
    private JPanel panelContainer;
    private JLabel lblFirstLabel;
    private JButton btnFirstButton;

    public MyWindow(){

        super("My first window"); //Sets the title
        this.panelContainer = new JPanel(new FlowLayout()) //Has FlowLayout by default but added it anyway
        this.lblFirstLabel = new JLabel("My First Label"); 
        this.btnFirstButton = new JButton("My First Button"); 
        panelContainer.add(lblFirstLabel); //Adds Label to Panel
        panelContainer.add(btnFirstButton); //Adds button to panel
        this.add(panelContainer); //Adds Panel with all comps to frame
        this.pack();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MyWindow().setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Be sure that everything is imported via import statements

I hope this helps